# Unable to select radio buttons using labels in ruby on rails while running through a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, radio-button, label

Here is the code I am writing for **RADIO BUTTON** in **RAILS**

```
<% @Days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'] %>
<% @Days.each do |day| %>
<%= f.radio_button :due_day, day, :checked => @group.due_day.eql?(day) %> 
<%= f.label :due_day, day %>
<% end %>
```

And at HTML I **get**

```
<input checked="checked" id="group_due_day_monday" name="group[due_day]" type="radio" value="Monday" /> 
<label for="group_due_day">Monday</label>
.....
.....
<input id="group_due_day_sunday" name="group[due_day]" type="radio" value="Sunday" /> 
<label for="group_due_day">Sunday</label>
```

but I want it to be **like**

```
<input checked="checked" id="group_due_day_monday" name="group[due_day]" type="radio" value="Monday" /> 
<label for="group_due_day_monday">Monday</label>
.....
.....
<input id="group_due_day_sunday" name="group[due_day]" type="radio" value="Sunday" /> 
<label for="group_due_day_sunday">Sunday</label>
```

So that if the label is clicked **RADIO BUTTON** gets selected. This can be achieved using

```
<%= f.radio_button :due_day, day, :checked => @group.due_day.eql?(day) %> 
<%= f.label :due_day_monday, day %>
```

But this is not good practice in case, if I have a set of **USERS** says **@users**. Where I dont know the **length** of the **array** and also the **users names** ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FormHelper `label`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label) accepts a `:value` option precisely for this scenario:

```
<% @Days.each do |day| %>
<%= f.radio_button :due_day, day, :checked => @group.due_day.eql?(day) %> 
<%= f.label :due_day, day, :value => day %>
<% end %>
```